# Extract relevent keywords from job advertisements

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

My friend asked me if I could write a program capable of identifying relevant keywords from job adverts knowing 3 variables: Industry, job title and the job posting text (example below).

The problem we are trying to address, from a job seeker's point of view, evolves around having the correct keywords in your resume for each job application hereby increasing your chances of getting shortlisted for an interview. This is especially important when the first stage screening is done by bots scanning for keywords.

Initially I was considering a relational database containing all industries, all job titles and their related keywords. This however is an enormous task and the data in progressive fields like information and bio technology would quickly become stale.

It seems machine learning and natural language processing is unavoidable.

Consider below job advert for a bank seeking a teller:

> Are you an experienced Bank Teller seeking that perfect work life
>   balance? If you’re looking for Casual Hours and have an absolute
>   passion for customer service then this is the role for you!
>
> Our client services Queensland Public Servants (particularly
>   Queensland Police); and is currently seeking a Bank Teller to join
>   their Brisbane CBD team to start ASAP.
>
> The successful candidate will be required to work from 9:30am to
>   2:30pm, Monday to Friday therefore 25 hours per week. Based on
>   experience the successful candidate will be paid (approximately) $25 -
>   $27 + superannuation per hour.
>
> This position is casual/temporary with the potential to for a
>   permanent placement (based on performance/length of assignment etc.).
>
> DUTIES & RESPONSIBILITIES:
>
> As a Bank Teller your will be required to:
>
> Attend to customers in a exceptional professional and efficient
>   manner; Processing basic transactions such as deposits and
>   withdrawals; Complete complex transactions such as loans and
>   mortgages; Pass referrals onto sales team (NO SALES); Large amounts of
>   cash handling; and Ensuring high attention to detail is at the top of
>   your list! SKILLS & EXPERIENCED:
>
> The successful candidate will have the following:
>
> Previous teller experience (within last 5 years) IDEAL; Previous
>   customer service experience (within finance) IDEAL; Ability to work in
>   a fast paced and time pressured environment; Excellent presentation
>   and attitude; Exceptional attention to detail; Ability to quickly
>   ‘master’ multiple software packages; and Strong time management skills
>   and ability to work autonomously. If you boast to have fantastic
>   customer service skills, a professional manner, and preferrably teller
>   experience we would LOVE to hear from you!

If I was the hiring manager (or a bot) I would probably look for these keywords in the resume:

> teller, transactions, deposits, withdrawals, loans, mortgages, customer
>   service, time management

How would you attack this problem?

Comment: A very interesting question, but unfortunately rather discursive and broad for Stack Overflow. Maybe there are some machine learning rooms over at Reddit?

Comment: Yes, I feared that the question was too broad for Stackoverflow. Perhaps this would fit better on Quora.

Comment: Yes, I think that would be a better fit as well, good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have access to lots of advertisements, group them by job title and then run a topic modelling algorithm such as Latent Dirichlet Allocation (LDA) on each group.  This will produce the keywords.

For more information see Relink who does exactly what you are trying to do.  They provide an outline of the process here:
[The Science Behind Relink - Organizing Job Postings](https://relinklabs.com/the-science-behind-relink-organizing-job-postings-1)

Here is a paper that may help: [Modeling Career Path Trajectories](https://mimno.infosci.cornell.edu/papers/07-69.pdf).

For a technical paper on just LDA see [Latent Dirichlet Allocation](http://ai.stanford.edu/~ang/papers/nips01-lda.pdf).

For an article with sample Python code using the gensim library see [Experiments on the English Wikipedia](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/wiki.html).  This is an interesting article as it deals with a huge corpus, a dump of the entire Wikipedia database, and talks about ways of improving execution times using distributed LDA on a cluster of computers.  The sample code also shows how to apply Latent Semantic Analysis and compares the results with LDA.

The following article and sample code by Jordan Barber, [Latent Dirichlet Allocation (LDA) with Python](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/79360_850b2a69980c4488b1db95987a24867a.html), uses NLTK to create a corpus and gensim for LDA.  This code is more adaptable to other applications than the Wikipedia code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Brian. Just needed a starting point so I'm going in the right direction. I will have a look at all of your links. Cheers.